# How to detect if browser is closed using jQuery

Tags: jquery, browser, navigation

I need to detect if the browser is being closed using jQuery, and do an event if this is true.  I have a chat feature on my website (much like Facebook) that keeps the user logged in as they navigate to other pages within the website structure but needs to log them out of chat (so they do not appear online to others) if they click the browsers close button. So `.unload()` will not work because .unload() will apply the logout function to all window actions including navigating to another page within the website structure. `.unload()` works for browser closes, but also works for browser forward and backward navigation, so I need a way to detect if the browser is being closed AND ONLY if the browser if being closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever you're using for chat (orbited, websockets?) should be able to detect a session timeout.

Comment: I'm using neither.  Because I'm new to this concept I'm probably executing this feature in not the best method.  when Tom types something into the textbox and presses enter to send to Jim, an ajax function calls a procedure in my program to submit (senderid, message, recipientid, time sent) into a table.  I then use a set interval loop (5secs) with an ajax request to query that table for anything with Jim's ID as the recipientid and displays the results in the chat box between Tom and Jim.  Somewhat convoluted, but it works nonetheless (not having access to an APE).

Comment: You're right, that's not the best method, but in that case just expect the request in a certain time since it's regular and force the session to expire when it doesn't happen.

Comment: No you don't understand, the request is being sent from the user to query a table on the server.  The server doesn't request anything from the browser.  And truthfully I don't know how to make it request anything from a particular user browser window.

Comment: Oh I see, you probably want a separate process on running on the server that checks lastupdate times from sessions on your table and then sets some flags or deletes the session if it's older than a certain time. When other users request info, they should see that user logged out.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this would be to set up some regular polling of the server to tell it that the user is still on the page.  You could send an AJAX request once a minute to confirm that the user is still there, and log them out on the server side if more than that time has gone by since the last notification.

This may not be the most reliable solution, but it is a very common one and will probably be effective for what you want to do.

Comment: What data would I query on for this regular polling? If they have closed their browser then there is no data coming in, so I could poll on some inactivity variable, however, I don't want to log them out if they have just left their chair for alittle while and intent on coming back.

Comment: Just use setInterval: `setInterval(function(){$.ajax({...}), 60 * 1000);`.  Do an AJAX request every minute and if a user's browser does not send the request, assume they have logged out.  You don't need to rely on any activity on the user's part.

Comment: But if the user browser is closed then it cannot and will not run any jQuery or Javascript functions like setInterval.

Comment: Exactly.  The absence of the AJAX call will tell your server that the user has closed the window.  Just to note, if you are already doing regular polling for updates, you could use these calls to allow the server to detect whether the user is still there.  This is, incidentally, how StackOverflow's chat system works, along with many others.

Comment: Unless you are suggesting I somehow have another function running on the server that requests the status of EVERY SINGLE user who is using the chat feature.  Which can get insanely high.

Comment: @sadmicrowave No. I'm suggesting that, every time you poll the server, you update the `last_polled` (or whatever) database field, and you run a cronjob every minute (or whatever) that logs out everyone who hasn't been seen in over a minute.  That should be pretty unobtrusive, especially if you use `nice`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. `onunload` / `onbeforeunload` are the only events that the system offers. The reason why a page is unloaded is not disclosed to the page.

It is possible to frequently check for whether a window *that your script opened* still exists. These solutions work based on `setInterval()` and the window's `closed` property. But I don't think that is what you're looking for.