# Run a function when the browser is closed Django

Tags: python, jquery, django, ajax, django-views

Based from what I've read there is no way of learning if the browser or a tab is closed by the user through Django. Ideally I think there should be no problem in closing the browser or a tab because the user is automatically logged out.

However, my problem is I have overridden my log-out view so Django does some functions (such as saving a time-stamp, and etc.) regarding the models relating to the logged in user. Django does not fire up these functions whenever the user logs out through closing the browser. It runs though when the user logs out normally through the "Log-Out" button.

This is my overridden log-out view:

```
def logout(request):
    reset_logged_acc(request) #do something
    auth_logout(request) #custom log-out
    return redirect('home')
```

I've read somewhere that I can do some ajax requests and what not to know if the user is still there. I think its possible but I'm putting that option up as a last resort if nothing comes up.

Are there any alternative ways to implement this?

Comment: Django can not know that someone has closed the browser, since the browser does not send a request for that.

Comment: I believe the answer to this question is the best you can do using client side code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24865561/detect-if-user-has-closed-all-windows-for-a-website

Comment: Here is a jQuery solution that uses an ajax request every minute or so https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096955/how-to-detect-if-browser-is-closed-using-jquery

Comment: Thanks @FSDford will look into these SO answers

Comment: @FSDford Considering if I choose to go with the ajax route, how will I implement this in Django? I have no problems in the client side on sending ajax requests, but I don't know how I can recognize in Django if it didn't receive any requests. Are there any timers or anything of some sort in Django so I can check for every n seconds?

Answer (score 0):

Found a work around for this though not pretty.

Basically, I just created a `request.session['window_num']` which represents the number windows generated from Django.

So this means for every GET request Django increments the session variable via `add_window(request)`.

To handle the deletion or closing of pages, I just used `navigator.sendBeacon` function enclosed by the `$(window).on('unload', function() {});` function in Javascript to send a request to Django. Django then decrements the session variable via `delete_window(request)`.

Then I added an if statement just before the function closes to check if the session variable goes to 0. If it goes to 0, it calls my overridden log-out function.

I admit this is not the best code for this so I'm still open for any improvements or alternatives. Just posted this because it works.

Tried the ajax request every n seconds thing but can't implement it in Django.

These are the following codes:

**navigator.sendBeacon**

```
$(window).on('unload', function() {
      var data = new FormData();        
      data.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', '{{csrf_token}}');
      navigator.sendBeacon("{% url 'delete_window' %}",data);
  });
```

**views.py**

```
@csrf_exempt
def delete_window(request):    
    window_num = int(request.session['window_num'])
    window_num -= 1
    request.session['window_num'] = str( window_num )
    
    if int( request.session['window_num'] ) == 0:
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            logout(request) #calls out overridden log-out function          

    data = {}
    return JsonResponse(data)

def add_window(request):
    if 'window_num' in list(request.session.keys()): #there are existing pages
        window_num = int(request.session['window_num'])
        window_num += 1 
        request.session['window_num'] = str( window_num )

    else: #first time load
        request.session['window_num'] = "1"
```

Comment: If I would take this aproach, I would do it just oposite, use the `sendBeacon()` to send requests on intervals as a dead-man button.